# Cannot resolve Babel plugins with Babel loader and Webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs, gulp-babel

I have the following Webpack config:

```
{
    resolveLoader: {
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.es6?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    presets: [
                        'es2015'
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        'transform-class-properties'
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My project structure:

```
.
+-- deploy
|   +-- node_modules
|   +-- Gulpfile.js
+-- es6
|   +-- Source files
```

The error I get:

```
ERROR in ../es6/src.es6
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-class-properties" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "[ABSOLUTE_PATH]/es6"
```

Seems like resolveLoader doesn't work for some reason.

Tried to remove the `transform-class-properties` plugin and I'll get the same error for the `es2015` preset.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you share your package.json? Are `babel-loader`and `babel-preset-es2015` added to your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Replace  loaders  x Rules:

```
 module: {
       loaders: [
            {
           }
        ]
     }
```

Comment: What does this do? How does it answer the question? Explain yourself!